# EJS and Express - How to pass data to tag attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to pass data object to my HTML page in some tags. This is the code:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js" poster="<%= data.placeholder %>" >

<source class="link" id="source" src="<%= data.video %>" type='video/mp4'>
```

and I get an error:

> ReferenceError: data is not defined

This is my Express code:

```
app.get('/lectures/:lecture', (req, res) => {
    const index = req.params.lecture;
    let data = {
        placeholder: `../img/placeholder${index}.svg`,
        video: videoURLs[index]
    };

    res.render('lectures', data);
});
```

So, how to pass data to tag attribute?

Comment: which UI engine you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your render functionality to:

`res.render('lectures', { data });`

Actually, it depends on ES version.
If you are using ES6 or ES6+, it is okay to use

```
res.render('lectures', { data });
```

If ES version lower than 6 (maybe ES5)
Use

```
res.render('lectures', { data: data});
```

Comment: can't accept it (not enough rep) but it's helped me. Thank you!